# Potential misunderstanding in reading Set Theory by Hrbacek

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

Currently I am reading *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbacek.

**Background:** First the author stated the axiom of pairing and the axiom of union as follows:

> **Axiom of union**: $\forall S:\exists U: \forall x: \big(x\in U\iff \exists A\in S: x\in A\big)$
> **Axiom of pairing:** $\forall A: \forall B: \exists C: \forall x:\big(x\in C\iff x=A\vee x=B\big)$

Then by proving the uniquess of the sets $U$ and $C$, respectively, we can introduce *The union of two sets* as a set theoretic operation.

**My problem:** The author claim is " **The axiom of union** is much more powerful; it enables us to form unions of not just two, but of any, possibly infinite, collection of sets."

**My doubt:** Should it not be/Doesn't he mean **The axiom of pairing** instead?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, the author is correct.

The Axiom of Pairing helps you to define sets $\{A,B\}$ whenever $A,B$ are sets. Then, by the Axiom of Union, you can form the set $\bigcup\{A,B\}$, usually denoted $A\cup B$.

You can now continue this process to form any union of *finitely many* sets, say $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$. However, using this strategy, you will not be able to make the jump to the union of infinitely many sets.

In fact, in order to form the union $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$, where $I$ is some indexing set, and all $A_i$ are just some arbitrary sets, you proceed as follows: Use the Axiom Schema of Replacement (see later in the book) to form the collection $\mathcal C=\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$, then form its union $\bigcup\mathcal C$ using the Axiom of Union, which is precisely what we mean by $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$. As $I$ could be infinite, the union could be as well.

Comment: So, the author is not correct in saying "...posibly infinite..."? Why posibly if it's not enough to make the jump to the union of infinitely many sets?

Comment: @HannyBoy No. If you wish to use the strategy with Axiom of Pairing, you can only get a finite union. But if you use the Axiom of Union as I did in the last part of my post, you can also get an infinite union. This is what the author meant.

Comment: You helped me understand, @Zuy, thank you.